# Google Earth Engine k-fold cross-validation

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, random-forest, geemap, cross-validation

I wrote a script for Google Earth Engine that allows me to analyze geospatial data. Initially, I loaded three data sets: a predictor shapefile, a forecast area shapefile, and a collection of landslide points.

I defined the column names of the predictors that I would use for my analysis. I added a 'Presence/absence' field to my predictor shapefile, which indicates whether a particular feature intersects with any landslide point.

I obtained a list of feature IDs and converted it into a JavaScript array. I then randomly shuffled this array using the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm.

I divided the data into k folds to perform k-fold cross-validation. For each fold, I took a subset of IDs for validation and used all other IDs for training.

I defined a Random Forest classification model and trained it on the training data. I then validated the model on the validation data.

After training and validating the model, I calculated the accuracy of the validated model using an error matrix.

Finally, I trained the classifier on the entire training dataset and calculated the prediction for the forecast area. I converted the classified prediction into an image and added it to the map.

Could someone tell me if this procedure is correct or if something needs to be changed?

I'm sharing the complete script right here:

````
// Load the shapefile for predictors from the specified project assets
var predictors_shp = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-gabrielenicolanapoli/assets/Marche_Lasli/gridcoll_predictors_test');
// Load the shapefile for the prediction area from the specified project assets
var prediction_area_shp = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-gabrielenicolanapoli/assets/Marche_Lasli/gridcoll_prediction_test');

// Load landslide points geometries
// Load the feature collection of landslide points from the specified project assets
var landPoints = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-gabrielenicolanapoli/assets/test_frane');

// Add layers to the map
// Center the map on the predictors shapefile with a zoom level of 12
Map.centerObject(predictors_shp, 12);

// Define predictor column names
// Define the names of the predictor columns to be used in the analysis
var predictors_column_name = ['Relief_mean', 'S_mean', 'VCv_mean', 'HCv_mean', 'NDVI_mean'];

// Add a 'value' field to predictors_shp based on intersection with landPoints
// Map over the predictors shapefile and add a 'Presence/absence' field
// This field is 1 if the feature intersects with any landslide points, and 0 otherwise
var predictors_with_values = predictors_shp.map(function(feature) {
  var intersects = landPoints.filterBounds(feature.geometry()).size();
  return feature.set('Presence/absence', ee.Number(intersects).gt(0));
});

// Get the list of feature IDs
// Aggregate the 'id' field from all features in the shapefile into a list
var ids = predictors_with_values.aggregate_array('id');

// Convert the list to an array
// This is necessary for further manipulation of the list with functions
ids = ids.getInfo();

// Create a function to shuffle an array
// This function randomly rearranges the elements of the input array
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
  
  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    
    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    
    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  
  return array;
}

// Create a copy of the ID array
// This is necessary to avoid modifying the original array when shuffling
var idsCopy = Array.from(ids);

// Define the number of k for your k-fold cross-validation
// This is the number of folds (subsets) the data will be split into for cross-validation
var k = 5;

// Calculate the number of elements per fold
// This is the size of each fold in the k-fold cross-validation
var numPerFold = Math.floor(ids.length / k);

// Create an array to store validation IDs
// This will hold the IDs of the features used for validation in each fold
var validationIds = [];

// Create an array to store training IDs
// This will hold the IDs of the features used for training in each fold
var trainingIds = [];

// Perform k-fold cross-validation
// Loop over each fold
for (var i = 0; i < k; i++) {
  // Take a subset of IDs for validation
  // Remove the first numPerFold elements from idsCopy and store them in validationIds[i]
  validationIds[i] = idsCopy.splice(0, numPerFold);
  
  // Use all other IDs for training
  // Copy the remaining elements in idsCopy to trainingIds[i]
  trainingIds[i] = Array.from(idsCopy);
  
  // Add validation IDs to the end of the ID array
  // Append the elements in validationIds[i] to idsCopy
  idsCopy = idsCopy.concat(validationIds[i]);
}

// Define your model here. For example, you could use a Random Forest classifier.
// Initialize a Random Forest classifier with 10 trees
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(20).setOutputMode('PROBABILITY');

// Loop over each fold again
for (var i = 0; i < k; i++) {
  // Create your training and validation datasets using the IDs
  // Filter the features in predictors_with_values by whether their 'id' is in trainingIds[i]
  var trainingData = predictors_with_values.filter(ee.Filter.inList('id', trainingIds[i]));
  // Filter the features in predictors_with_values by whether their 'id' is in validationIds[i]
  var validationData = predictors_with_values.filter(ee.Filter.inList('id', validationIds[i]));

  // Train the model
  // Train the classifier on the training data, using 'Presence/absence' as the class and predictors_column_name as the features
  var trainedModel = classifier.train(trainingData, 'Presence/absence', predictors_column_name);

  // Validate the model
  // Classify the validation data using the trained model
  var validatedData = validationData.classify(trainedModel);
  
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  // After model training and validation
  // Classify the validation data using the trained model
  var validatedData = validationData.classify(trainedModel);

  // Reduce the FeatureCollection to an image
  // Convert the classified validation data to an image, using the 'classification' property
  var image = validatedData.reduceToImage(['classification'], ee.Reducer.first());

  // Define visualization parameters
  // Define the parameters for visualizing the image, with 'red' representing 0 and 'green' representing 1
  var visParams = {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['red', 'green']};

  // Add the image to the map
  // Add the image to the map, using the defined visualization parameters
  Map.addLayer(image, visParams, 'Results');

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  // Calculate accuracy
  // Calculate the accuracy of the validated model using an error matrix
  var accuracy = validatedData.errorMatrix('Presence/absence', 'classification').accuracy();

  // Print accuracy for each iteration
  // Print the accuracy of the model for each fold of the cross-validation
  print('Accuracy at iteration ' + i + ':', accuracy);
}

// Add the landslide points to the map
Map.addLayer(landPoints,{},'landPoints');

// After model training
// Train the classifier on the entire training dataset
var trainedModel = classifier.train(trainingData, 'Presence/absence', predictors_column_name);

// Calculate prediction for prediction_area_shp
// Classify the prediction area using the trained model
var prediction = prediction_area_shp.classify(trainedModel);

// Reduce the FeatureCollection to an image
// Convert the classified prediction to an image, using the 'classification' property
var predictionImage = prediction.reduceToImage(['classification'], ee.Reducer.first());

// Define visualization parameters
// Define the parameters for visualizing the prediction image, with 'red' representing 0 and 'green' representing 1
var visParams = {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['red', 'green']};

// Add the prediction image to the map
// Add the prediction image to the map, using the defined visualization parameters
Map.addLayer(predictionImage, visParams, 'Prediction');```
````

Comment: To be curious, without knowing the answer. Since I haven't used a classifier object in GEE yet (I'm used to TF and Sklearn), when you declare the classifier out of the loop (`var classifier = ...`), then you train the model k times inside the loop, the clasiffier is resetted in each iteration? Some objects reclicles the information and re-train instead of a starting again. You approach looks great for me, congrats

Comment: Looks reasonable, except you could use List.shuffle or collection.randomColumn+sort on the server side instead of fiddling around with indices on the client (skips getInfo).